# Apache2 config: Exclude one IP from listening

Tags: apache-2.2

Got server with bunch of ip adresses. Any way to force Apache to listen on all of them except one without having to put every ip on the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't seem possible. Either you can use the following Listen directives which will listen to all ipv4 addresses.

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
```

Or you have to manually list all the ip addresses you want the server to listen to.

If you look at the syntax, there is no such option to manipulate:

> Syntax:   Listen [IP-address:]portnumber [protocol]

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mpm_common.html#listen